# Why there are two brightness control file (/sys/class/) in my system

Tags: 12.04, brightness, nvidia-optimus

I own an dell xps 15. I guess the following is because I have hybrid graphics system (nvidia optimus).

When I run command to find out lcd brightness path using following command,

> ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness

I receive the following output

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Now if I echo a value say `5` to either of them, LCD brightness changes. Only thing is `intel_backlight` path brightness is very low compared to `acpi_video0`.

Is it normal? I want to know what is the difference (if any) and whether for this two different paths gnome fails to save my brightness settings on reboot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brightness could be controlled by ACPI or by graphic driver. I suppose the one that controls your brightness is intel_backlight.
However, you could easy find it out adding to your /etc/rc.local (before exit 0):

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

or, alternatively:

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

It seems that Fn-Keys do change the value of acpi_video0, the problem is that the controlling item is intel_backlight.

If the system starts with the kernel parameter acpi_backlight=vendor, the item acpi_video0 is replaced by the item intel, but then the Fn-Keys can not change the value of this item.

Comment: Changing kernel parameter actually worked. I got more steps in brightness control switch.