# Screen brightness turns off at boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot

Whenever I boot up Ubuntu from the grub menu, the screen brightness goes to zero. And cannot see anything unless I turn it up. I know a way to solve this is to press the brightness button until the screen is visible, but it's annoying having to do that all the time. Is there a way to keep it at a certain brightness level? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try if this helps:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/134984/why-there-are-two-brightness-control-file-sys-class-in-my-system/137887#137887

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a python script that sets brightness on login.

I followed this guide: [Set-brightness-automatically-at-the-startup-in-linux](http://blog.ishans.info/2011/09/25/set-brightness-automatically-at-the-startup-in-linux/)

1. Download this script: http://ishans.info/attachments/article/65/setBrightness.py (it's the second one from the guide above)
2. Save the script somewhere it won't get moved, like /home/stephen/Documents/setBrightness.py
3. Set brightness level to 100. Do this by editing the script's last line to read `iface.SetPercentage(100)`
4. Autostart Script. Do this by launching Startup Applications > Add
   Name: setBrightness
   Command: `python /home/stephen/Documents/setBrightness.py`
5. Enjoy

This script will not take affect until you log on.
This script can also be used to intentionally dim the screen on startup by skipping step 3.